# Suppress XCode Analyzer Potential leak of an object stored into a .. error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, analyzer

I have a method that creates an returns an instance of a `CoreGraphics` object - `CGPathRef`.

When I run the app through Analyzer it complains that this method is leaking...it is , but it is deliberate. I do want to transfer the ownership to the caller and let them clean up.

What can I do to suppress this *Analyzer* warning?

```
- (CGPathRef) createSomePath:(CGPoint)center innerRadius:(CGFloat)innerRadius outerRadius:(CGFloat)outerRadius startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle
{
  CGMutablePathRef slicePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

  ....

  return slicePath;  <--- Analyzer points to this line as a potential leak.
}
```

Assume this should be possible as lots of frameworks return these objects requiring the caller to clean up...

Thanks in advance !

P.S. Am afraid that this question is not a dup nor does not have a proper answer anywhere else...the 3 answers highlighted at the top of this page are not proper/complete...only the answer provided here by Matthias Bauch i.e. "new" rule is truly the right answer to the question I raised :) THANKS!

Comment: I did this a while ago ;-)

Comment: @moonwalker It isn't magic;  `Create` is CF* nomenclature.  `+new` is Objective-c nomenclature.   `+create` means nothing in Objective-C.

Comment: @bbum - of course I do realize it is the "create rule" -- magic is just a figure of speech..:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CoreFoundation functions follow the ["create rule"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). If the function has a "Create" in it it returns an object with a reference count of 1.

Unfortunately your method is not a c function.

So you should turn your Objective-C method into a C function. Something like this:

```
CGPathRef CreatePath(CGPoint center, CGFloat innerRadius, CGFloat outerRadius, CGFloat startAngle, CGFloat endAngle) {
    // your code here
}
```

This should please the analyzer and work correctly with ARC.

In a Objective-C method you can get similar behaviour by starting your method signature with [`new`, `alloc`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). Starting the method with `new` probably fits your case best.
Something like this should please the analyzer, but I am not sure if it works correctly with ARC. You have to profile this.

```
- (CGPathRef)newPath:(CGPoint)center innerRadius:(CGFloat)innerRadius outerRadius:(CGFloat)outerRadius startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Awesome - newPath worked for Analyzer. Assume ARC will not have a problem with it but will keep an eye on it.... Thank you Matt. Accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
CGMutablePathRef slicePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
#endif
```

I can't say I recommend it though!

Comment: Did this not work? I just tested it myself and it's working for me.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I wasn't sure who it was. Is this only when you run *Product > Analyze*?

Comment: yes...and if you put the #ifndef around the assignment CGMutablePathRef slicePath = CGPathCreateMutable(); rather than return it does work...I already up voted your answer form -1 to 0... :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I edited my answer; does that look like what's working for you? It's also working for me when I do it that way.

Comment: yes...it suppresses the warning with correction...however I do not understand the drawbacks of using this approach...can you share you thoughts ?

Comment: If you work with other developers, they may not expect to have to manage memory whenever they call your method. Passing a CGRefPath by reference is a possible alternative.